# Can we access interpolated values inside another interpolation?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, interpolation, curly-braces

### I am trying to show 1 value using interpolation which is inside another interpolation. For eg:

```
<div *ngFor="let det of values">
{{det.firstname}}{{det.lastname}}
</div>
```

---

### The above will print fine but now the firstname and last name will be dynamic and will come from another variable name eg:

```
<div *ngFor="let det of values">
<span *ngFor="let n of names">(n will contain firstname and lastname)
{{det.n}}
</span>
</div>
```

---

Could I please request for a suggestion on this. How can I achieve this thing.

Comment: Have you tried `{{det[n]}}`?

Comment: How are your lists structured?

Comment: @yurzui Yes det[n did the trick Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

det.n, the 'n' is a attribute-name so cannot be dynamic;

you can make det as a array,like this:

```
var det=[];
det['jack']='boy';
det['tom']='boy';
```

then you can get the value with det['jack'], you will get the value 'boy';

Comment: No i did not want to make another array but {{det[n]}} worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by:

```
values: any[] = [
    { "firstName": "fname1", "lastName": "lname1" },
    { "firstName": "fname2", "lastName": "lname2" }
];

names: any[] = [ "firstName", "lastName" ];

<div *ngFor="let det of values">
    <span *ngFor="let n of names"> {{ det[n] }} </span>
</div>
```